# org-mode : add an attribute or a property to the result of a call

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

Let suppose our program output many formatted tables.

For instance :

```org
#+Name: Scores
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output raw

from random import randint
li ='''Max Charlie Cooper Buddy Jack Rocky Oliver Bear Duke Tucker'''.split()
print(  "|{0:8s}| {1:3s} | {2:3s} | {3:3s} |".format(
      "Name","str","agi","int"
))

for f in li:
  print("|{0:8s}| {1:3d} | {2:3d} | {3:3d} |".format(
     *( [f]+[randint(0,20) for x in range(3)])
  ))

#+END_SRC   

#+Call: Scores()
```

The evaluation of the code block will produce an output similar to this

```
#+RESULTS:
| Name    | str | agi | int |
| Max     |  17 |  15 |  16 |
| Charlie |   2 |   5 |  19 |
| Cooper  |   3 |   5 |   5 |
| Buddy   |   9 |   6 |   9 |
| Jack    |  11 |  14 |  19 |
| Rocky   |  19 |   1 |   2 |
| Oliver  |   5 |  17 |   5 |
| Bear    |   0 |  17 |  17 |
| Duke    |  16 |   8 |  19 |
| Tucker  |  14 |  13 |   9 |
```

When exporting, the `#+CALL` is evaluated,
and its results gets exported.

**Question**: how to automate the insertion of something like

```
#+ATTR_LaTeX: :center nil :align |p{5cm}|l|l|l|
```

on top of the table in the results section ?

Any proposal is welcome, be it by outputting by value, hooking the export, creating a latex header... or indicating any appropriate org function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `:prologue` header is appended to the body of the block before execution:

```org
#+Name: Scores
#+header: :prologue print('#+ATTR_LaTeX: :center nil :align |p{5cm}|l|l|l|')
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output raw :exports results :eval yes

from random import randint
li ='''Max Charlie Cooper Buddy Jack Rocky Oliver Bear Duke Tucker'''.split()
print(  "|{0:8s}| {1:3s} | {2:3s} | {3:3s} |".format(
      "Name","str","agi","int"
))

for f in li:
  print("|{0:8s}| {1:3d} | {2:3d} | {3:3d} |".format(
     *( [f]+[randint(0,20) for x in range(3)])
  ))

#+END_SRC

#+results: Scores
#+ATTR_LaTeX: :center nil :align |p{5cm}|l|l|l|
|Name    | str | agi | int |
|Max     |   9 |  13 |  17 |
|Charlie |  12 |   7 |  10 |
|Cooper  |  16 |  19 |   7 |
|Buddy   |  16 |   2 |  13 |
|Jack    |  17 |  10 |  20 |
|Rocky   |   0 |  19 |  13 |
|Oliver  |  17 |   2 |   6 |
|Bear    |  19 |  20 |  17 |
|Duke    |   8 |  19 |   9 |
|Tucker  |   1 |  10 |   7 |
```

Comment: This is a little cleaner than the :post solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the :post header and a named block that adds that. https://orgmode.org/manual/post.html#post

Here is an example modified from that page.

```
#+name: attr_wrap
#+begin_src sh :var data=""  :results output
  echo "#+ATTR_LATEX: :center nil :align |p{5cm}|l|l|l|"
  echo "$data"
#+end_src


#+Name: Scores
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output raw :post attr_wrap(data=*this*) 

from random import randint
li ='''Max Charlie Cooper Buddy Jack Rocky Oliver Bear Duke Tucker'''.split()
print(  "|{0:8s}| {1:3s} | {2:3s} | {3:3s} |".format(
      "Name","str","agi","int"
))

for f in li:
  print("|{0:8s}| {1:3d} | {2:3d} | {3:3d} |".format(
     *( [f]+[randint(0,20) for x in range(3)])
  ))

#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: Scores
#+ATTR_LATEX: :center nil :align |p{5cm}|l|l|l|
| Name    | str | agi | int |
| Max     |  12 |   4 |  10 |
| Charlie |  15 |  10 |  10 |
| Cooper  |  17 |  13 |  20 |
| Buddy   |   6 |  15 |  11 |
| Jack    |   8 |  15 |  16 |
| Rocky   |   1 |  16 |   6 |
| Oliver  |   9 |  11 |  14 |
| Bear    |  10 |   6 |   3 |
| Duke    |   2 |  19 |   1 |
| Tucker  |   8 |   0 |   2 |
```

Comment: This opens a new range of possibilities